# How to match string A which does not contain string A

Tags: c#, regex

From `.*tan(.*tan(.*)).*`, and only `.*tan(.*tan(.*)).*`, I want to match the inner `tan(.*)`.

---

### Regex

```
tan\([0-9a-zA-Z\.\+\-\*\/\(\)![tan]]+\)
```

---

### Example

From:

```
tan(80.1*tan(81.7+(80.9+81.5)))+81.9
```

I want to extract the inner:

```
tan(81.7+(80.9+81.5))
```

But not:

```
tan(80.1*tan(81.7+(80.9+81.5)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I cannot use the operators `and` and `not` to filter out the most inner `tan`, I finally tried out:

```
public String MatchExtra(string head, string extra)
{
    string result = "";

    if (!head.Contains(extra))
        return head;

    string criteria = extra + "\\([a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\+\\-\\*\\/]+\\)";
    MatchCollection match1 = Regex.Matches(head, criteria, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    foreach (Match bracket_match in match1)
    {
        if (bracket_match.Success)
        {   // not finish if bracket have bracket
            for (int y = 0; y < bracket_match.Captures.Count; y++)
            {
                string a = bracket_match.Captures[y].ToString();
                string b = bracket_match.Captures[y].ToString().Substring(extra.Length + 1, bracket_match.Captures[y].ToString().Length - extra.Length - 2);
                result = MatchExtra(bracket_match.Captures[y].ToString().Substring(extra.Length + 1, bracket_match.Captures[y].ToString().Length - extra.Length - 2), extra);
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    string criteria2 = extra + "\\(.*\\)";
    MatchCollection match2 = Regex.Matches(head,  criteria, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    foreach (Match bracket_match in match2)
    {
        if (bracket_match.Success)
        {   // not finish if bracket have bracket
            for (int y = 0; y < bracket_match.Captures.Count; y++)
            {
                string a = bracket_match.Captures[y].ToString();
                string b = bracket_match.Captures[y].ToString().Substring(extra.Length+1, bracket_match.Captures[y].ToString().Length - extra.Length -2);
                result = MatchExtra(bracket_match.Captures[y].ToString().Substring(extra.Length+1, bracket_match.Captures[y].ToString().Length - extra.Length-2), extra);
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **three** regexes. (I know! Crazy, isn't it?)

First extract:

```
^tan\(.*?tan\(.*?\).*?\)$
```

Then extract:

```
^(?=(tan\(.*?))tan\(.*?\).*$
```

Then extract:

```
^tan\(.*?\)(?=(.*?\).*?))$
```

---

If you're using Perl, it's a lot easier:

```
$mystr =~ s\^.*?tan\(.*?(tan\(.*?\)).*?\).*$\$1\;
```

---

**EDIT:**

I do not know *exactly* what you want, but judging from your comment on @Thorbear's post, I do not think you should be using regexes. You can't parse Context-Free Grammars with [C#] regexes alone.

What you need is an expression **parser**, not a regex.

Comment: it is not only two tan, if there are many tan, expect to get the most inner tan(XXX) first, why not exclude tan?

Answer (score 1):

Slightly unsure of your requirements... but something like `tan\(.*?(tan\(.*\))\)` will store the inner tan() in `$1`

For your character groups, you do not need to escape the characters `[0-9a-zA-Z.+*/-]` will suffice, just be careful of where you place the `-`

Edit:
If you have an unknown amount of tan() inside each other, you'd need something like `tan\((.(?!tan))*?\)` to capture the innermost one. You will however have to balance the parentheses afterwards, as a subject like `tan(80.1*tan(81.7+(80.9+81.5)))` will return the match `tan(81.7+(80.9+81.5)`. Furthermore if your subject looks like `tan(80.1*tan(81.7+(80.9+81.5)+(80.9+81.5)))` the pattern will not capture the last `(80.9+81.5)`, removing the last `?` will solve this, but then you will have problems with subjects like `tan(80.1*tan(81.7+(80.9+81.5)))+(80.9+81.5)` as it will capture the last expression as well.

Bottom Line is, like mentioned above, this is not a task for regex alone.

Comment: if there are many tan(x+tan(x+tan(x))), the requirement is to get the most inner tan first

Comment: You cannot use __only__ regexes for _that_! But your question is still unclear.

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args){
    var str = "tan(80.1*tan(81.7+(80.9+81.5)))+81.9";

    Console.WriteLine(innerTan(str));
}
static string innerTan(string str){
    const string token = "tan(";
    if(!str.Contains(token))
        return String.Empty;

    var spos = str.IndexOf(token);
    var epos = spos + token.Length;
    var balance = 1;
    for(var i = epos ;i < str.Length;++i){
        switch (str[i]){
        case '(':
            ++balance;break;
        case ')':
            --balance;break;
        }
        if(balance == 0){
            epos = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    var innerText = str.Substring(spos + token.Length, epos - spos);
    if(innerText.Contains(token))
        return innerTan(innerText);
    else
        return str.Substring(spos, epos - spos + 1);
}
```

Comment: C#(.NET) I probably would not take that the regex parenthesis balance.

Comment: Perhaps impossible. In regular expressions, I can not match the number of brackets to fit on the left and right parenthesis. (Maybe Perl can do)